# NSEntityDescription Cannot find type 'Personal' in scope

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I am working with core data. Currently I have on entity. I want to add another one, but for some reason I get a error on this line of code:

```
lazy var personalItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Personal", into: context) as! Personal
```

**Cannot find type 'Personal' in scope**

I initialized the other entity exactly the same way, and it works fine. Why doesn't it work with this entity?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem, I have now found a solution.
Emptying the Build Folders did not work for me. I restarted xCode again and after that it worked.